# iOs: How to change color of "more" back button when having more than 5 tabs

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application with 6 tabs, so the system automatically generates the first 4 tabs and a fifth tab called "Altro" ("More" in italian) that contains the previous fifth and sixth tab content.

This is ok. The problem is that i don't know how to change the color of the back button when going through the "altro" tab. Any advice?

Some screenshot for a better explanation of the problem:

[image: Orange back button]

[image: Altro tab]

[image: Blue back button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width/2, buttonImage.size.height/2);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(backPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```

Try this.......once

Comment: This works; but it's not what i wanted to do... i don't want to come out with tons of new button images, i just want to change the background color of the normal back buttons. Thank you anyway (I will use this method if I can't figure out another one!).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of backButton using the following code:

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];`

Comment: Nope: still blue... don't really know why!